# Read formatted (downloaded) text into messagebox

Tags: c#, messagebox

By downloading a string from the web, is it possible to make the messagebox read values like `\r\n` or `Environment.Newline`, that are written inside the text  downloaded ?

The online text message contains: `First line \r\n Second line` (into a textfile)... i would like to out put this inside the messagebox as it is formatted in the file.

```
var message = await RemoteHandler.GetWebContent(RemoteHandler.RemoteMessageUrl);
MessageBox.Show(message, "Title", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
```

**Current output:**

First line \r\n Second line

**Wanted output:**

First line
Second Line

Comment: Yes, `\r\n` should display in a message box as a new line. What is happening currently?

Comment: It reading the whole string currently (as expected), so yes `\r\n` is there. Thats where my question will be entered. Is it possible to intercept `\r\n` as a new line instead of just the string

Comment: I have a hunch that it has something to do with string encoding. I have not been able to reproduce on my end though. In what encoding is your remote string?

Comment: I get the string in my message box like so `First line \r\n Second line`. The wanted output is no `\r\n` but a newline instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some different test cases, I have determined that your `\r\n` is most likely stored as `\\r\\n` in your string which would cause the `\r\n` to print as a string literal instead of an `Environment.NewLine`. You should use one of the the following code to correct this string:

```
message = message.Replace("\\r\\n", Environment.NewLine);
message = message.Replace(@"\r\n", Environment.NewLine);
```

By using the double backslash, the carriage return and new line characters are being escaped and thus being printed literally. This is either a data issue or an issue with how the string is being loaded from the remote resource. However, this should get your new lines printing correctly within the message box.

Comment: Yes sir ... this will do the trick (added `@"\r\n` to your answer also. Thanks Cameron +1